# How do I add a rest in SmartMusic's Compose?

Tags: notation, software, rests

I've just started learning SmartMusic's Compose feature whereby I can create my own musical score.  I'm starting with *Mary Had a Little Lamb* (the hello world program equivalent for any music notation software).

**How do I add rests?**

I know I've done this before but can't remember how.

Searching for this has not found anything useful.

Comment: Consider joining the SmartMusic knowledge base and community forums if you haven’t already.

Comment: @PatS What is 'hello world program equivalent'?

Answer (score 2):

In the PDF documentation [here](https://smartmusic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026215274-Compose-User-Guide), it says you can press the zero (0) key to enter a rest of a specific duration, so if you've selected a half-note, and press the zero key, a half-note rest is entered.

To switch an existing note to a rest, press the s-key.  The s-key switches a note to a rest or a rest to a note.

This video shows using the s-key.

(no longer working)

Comment: The video link is dead.

Comment: It's gone for me too.... And I published it.  I'm guessing YouTube didn't like me doing that.